# Calling Javascript on Wordpress Responsive Tooltip

Tags: javascript, wordpress, responsive-design, tooltip

So I read through Wordpress' article on calling javascript in a specific page.

I want in on only one page since I am only using the script on that one page.

The tutorial I am using for the tooltip is here:

http://osvaldas.info/elegant-css-and-jquery-tooltip-responsive-mobile-friendly

I figure I am calling the script incorrectly:

Here is the code I am using on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.frgraphicsolutions.com/working/wp-content/themes/responsive-child/tooltip.js"></script>

<abbr title="We provide companies with advice and best practices on how to promote and     advance your graphic marketing projects. Our consultative approach analyzes your current practices and offers ideas on how to lower your costs and increase the effectiveness of your (limited) marketing budget." rel="tooltip"><img style="vertical-align: middle;" alt="" src="http://frgraphicsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/001.png" /></abbr> 

<abbr style:"float: right" title="We offer turn-key programs for small and medium-sized business to build your brand and establish an online presence, including the development of web pages, social media and lead-generation email campaigns. Services include graphic design and copywriting." rel="tooltip"><img style="vertical-align: middle;" alt="" src="http://frgraphicsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/002.png" /></abbr>
```

It isn't working and I am still very confused on how to call the javascript on wordpress.

Could someone clarify?

Thank you so very much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here is the solution I have figured out with some serious internet searching and help from wordpress forums:

1.Make a change to the Javascript so it is noConflict (As Ivan Hanak Stated)

First line turns into this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($)
```

Reference:

- [jQuery noConflict Wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

  2.Make a function.php file in my cild theme

  **I wanted to make sure that the function only works on one page of my website so that it doesn't slow down my sites performance**

So the php for the file looks like this:

```
<?php
if ( !function_exists( 'tool_tips' ) ) {
function tooltips() {
if ( is_page( 'Services' ) ) {
wp_enqueue_script( 'tooltips', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/tooltips.js', '', '1.0', true );
   }
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tooltips' );

?>
```

the

> is_page

function lets me call to whatever specific page(s) I want the java to load on.

Reference (On Wordpress.org Codex):

- Function Reference/wp enqueue script
- Function Reference/is page
- Child Themes

Thanks for all your help, it took a lot of digging but I have a better functioning site now!

Answer (score 1):

I looked up your site, I found a problem, why it might not work. You need to edit your script to use jQuery no conflict syntax.

Open your tooltip.js

and the very first line

```
$( document ).ready( function()
```

change into

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($)
```

This 'situation' described as [`jQuery noConflict Wrappers`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

> I am still very confused on how to call the JavaScript on WordPress.

For this, use Google, WordPress article is here[`enqueueing a script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: Exactly, two very basic things that most people get wrong, use `wp_enqueue_scripts` and wrap the jQuery code in noConflict. +1

Comment: So when I call it should the code look something like this?  `<?
php wp_enwueue_script('tooltips', content_url('/working/wp-content/themes/responsive-child/tooltip.js'); ?>`

Comment: Yes, but your url use rather like get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/tooltip.js'

Comment: Would it be better to change the location of the file? Or does it not matter since I want to keep the javascript in the child-theme file to link to it this way?

Comment: So when I put in:  `<?php get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/tooltip.js'; ?>`  It doesn't call the javascript still. Is this due to the location of the .js file? Since it is not located in the wp-includes folder but in a different directory?